Is there a better way to remove the protective film from a new refrigerator?
My stainless steel refrigerator has remnants of the pink protective plastic around the edges, by the gaskets, hinges, controls, etc.  The plastic film appears to go completely underneath the plastic and probably to the very edge of the stainless steel panels that are hidden.
Possibly the installers were a little too hasty when they peeled the plastic off and it ripped, but regardless of the reason there's ugly little pink bits sticking out 1/16 of an inch or so.  I've been cutting these out with a razor blade and tweezers, but am I being stupid and there's a much simpler way to clean these up?
